# Will two entities get written to datastore with this endpoint?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have an endpoint method that first uses a query to see if an entity with certain params exists, and if it does not it will create it. If it exists, I want to increase a counter in the variable:

```
Report report = ofy().load().type(Report.class)
    .filter("userID", userID)
    .filter("state", state).first().now();

if (report == null) { 
    //write new entity to datastore with userID and state
} else {
    //increase counter in entity +1
    report.setCount(report.count+1)
    //save entity to datastore
}
```

My question is, what if someone clicks a button to execute the above endpoint with the same params very rapidly, what will happen? Will two  identical Report entities get written to the datastore? I only want to make sure one is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself this code is not safe and has a race condition that will allow multiple Reports to be created.

To make this safe, you need to run the code in a transaction. Which means you must have an ancestor query (or convert it to a simple primary key lookup). One option is to give Report a `@Parent` of the User. Then you can so something like this:

```
ofy().transact(() -> {
    Report report = ofy().load().type(Report.class)
        .ancestor(user)
        .filter("state", state).first().now();

    if (report == null) { 
        //write new entity to datastore with userID and state
    } else {
        //increase counter in entity +1
        report.setCount(report.count+1)
        //save entity to datastore
    }
});
```

Comment: So if I did what you wrote in the code above, what would happen if someone executed my method very rapidly in a short period of time? Would the calls just queue up or something? Would there be some delay as this happens before a response is given back to the client?

Comment: The datastore uses an optimistic concurrency model, which means the low-level API will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` for all but 1 transaction. Objectify takes this as a cue to retry. So you'll get transactions committed at the max rate for a single entity group (typically 1-5 per second) and all other requests will spin/block waiting. If it goes on long enough requests will timeout. You do not want a lot of contention on a single entity group.